# link shared object with static library

Tags: c++, gcc, static, linker

my problem is:

i want to compile a shared object (called Dll.so) that link a static lib called for example (libstatic.a).

My objective is to have only Dll.so shared object.

```
LIBS:= -lm -ldl
LIBS+= -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,-Bstatic -llibstatic -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc
```

I have ggc_s error: cannot find -lgcc_s

Someone can help me?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

[-Bstatic](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523258) will link all following libraries as static. The error you see is probably related to something you have later in the cmd line. Instead use path to static library like so:

```
LIBS+= -Wl,--whole-archive my_lib_path/libstatic.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```